# 'Bridged' and 'Host Only' network settings in Virtualbox - Advice please

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm setting up a mini Penetration-testing lab, for training purposes, in Virtualbox. I want to connect to the Host Machine's wifi.

Is it possible to create a ‘Bridged’ network connection to a Host computer, for one Virtual Machine and a separate 'Host Only' network for a different Virtual Machine?

I need the two Virtual Machines to have separate I.P.s for penetration-testing purposes. I want to keep Metasploitable as 'Host Only' as it has a lot of vulnerabilities.

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: *Is it possible to create a ‘Bridged’ network connection to a Host computer, for one Virtual Machine and a separate 'Host Only' network for a different Virtual Machine?* Of course. You have 8 networking adapters which can be configured separately and independently. So set up one adapter as Bridged and connect 1st VM to it, set up another adapter as HostOnly and connect 2nd VM to it. To communicate with both VMs in the same time from Host configure networking adapters to different non-overlapping subnets.

Comment: I am grateful for your prompt response. I have Kali on 'Bridged' and Metasploitable on 'Host only' so that I can attack it for practice. Is that set-up feasible and safe? Would it be better to create 2 network-adapters in Virtualbox (vboxnet1 and vboxnet1, for example) and assign one to Kali and one to Metasploitable? I have heard Metasploitable is like a red-rag to a bull to hackers so I don't want it to have access to my host machine, even via Kali.

Comment: *Would it be better to create 2 network-adapters in Virtualbox* You MUST do it if you want to have different types of connection. But you will NO have a possibility to access to one VM from another VM (in both directions, of course), except the variant when your Host OS is configured for to route this traffic between those networking adapters.

Comment: I gather I will still be able to attack Metasploitable from Kali, via wifi, as if it is a separate computer on the internet.  This would be perfect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: *I gather I will still be able to attack Metasploitable from Kali, as if it is a separate computer on the internet.* No. Or rather you need to attack (successfully!) your Host to be able to attack another VM.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like what you want is this:

- VM A can not talk to anything beyond the host system.
- VM B can talk to anything, as well as being able to talk to VM A
- The host system can talk to either VM.

There are a couple of ways to achieve this.

The first and simplest is to just give VM B two network interfaces, one bridged to the host's main network interface, and the other connected to the host-only network that VM A is connected to.  This approach has the advantage that it's simple, easy to set up, easy to understand, and should just work without any need for special configuration in either of the VM's.

Other possible approaches, with varying degrees of difficulty, include:

- Create a virtual network bridge (not a VBox bridged interface, but a native network bridge) on the host that isn't connected to any physical interfaces, and configure it as a local isolated network.  Set up both VM's to use that as a network, and then configure the host's firewall and routing rules to allow only VM B to connect outside that network.
- Set up both hosts on a single host-only network, and then use the host system's firewall and routing rules to allow VM B access to external networks.
- Set up each host on it's own host-only network, and configure routing between them so that they can talk, then set up routing so that only VM B can get to other systems beyond that.

Comment: My main concern is shielding the host system (i.e. my Mac) from Metasploitable because it's full of deliberate vulnerabilities and limiting the interactivity to between the two VMs, Kali (the attacker) and Metasploitable (the victim). I've been told never to expose Metasploitable to a hostile network as it's like a red rag to a bull for hackers. I'll have a good look at your info and study up on what you've suggested as all this is quite new to me. Thanks.

Comment: @N008Y In that case, go with my first suggestion, but look into the 'Internal Network' option in VirtualBox.  That one does all the network handling inside VirtualBox itself, so there's no risk of network communications with the host.  The downside is that you will have to manually configure the network in the VM's (or run a DHCP server on one of them).

Comment: @N008Y Just to clarify, by first suggestion, I meant the approach of having two NIC's on the Kali VM, not the virtual network bridge method.  I just realized that I may not have been clear about this.

Comment: Okay. I'll research your info and hopefully all this will become clearer. Cheers.